# module outer variables aren't updating - r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the main shiny server I have a reactivePoll variable. I am trying to share this updating variable with shiny modules. It shows the initial value but it doesn't update. I am trying to get it to update.

Here is a reprex:

```
library(shiny)

# Module ----

# module ui
mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  
  verbatimTextOutput(ns("random_num"))
}

# module server
mod <- function(id, number) {
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$random_num <- renderPrint(number)
  }
  moduleServer(id, server)
}


# Shiny App ----

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$span("working random_num"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test"),
  tags$span("not working, module random num"),
  mod_ui("mod_id")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  random_num <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 1000,
    session = NULL,
    checkFunc = function()runif(1),
    valueFunc = function()runif(1)
  )
  
  output$test <- renderPrint(random_num())
  
  mod("mod_id", number = random_num())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a solution. Save the reactivePoll variable into a reactiveValue. Observe the reactiveValue. Curious why this is the case.

```
library(shiny)

# Module ----

# module ui
mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  
  verbatimTextOutput(ns("random_num"))
}

# module server
mod <- function(id, number) {
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$random_num <- renderPrint(number$test)
  }
  moduleServer(id, server)
}


# Shiny App ----

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$span("working random_num"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test"),
  tags$span("not working, module random num"),
  mod_ui("mod_id")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  test <- reactiveValues(
    test = runif(1)
  )
  
  random_num <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 1000,
    session = NULL,
    checkFunc = function()runif(1),
    valueFunc = function()runif(1)
  )
  
  observe(
    test$test <- random_num()
  )
  
  output$test <- renderPrint(random_num())
  
  mod("mod_id", number = test)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```